# first example merge documentation generates error

Tags: neo4j

on http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-merge.html

first example

```
MERGE (robert:Critic)
RETURN robert, labels(robert)
```

generates the following error:

```
Query:
merge (robert:Critic)
return robert, labels(robert)
Error: Invalid input 'c': expected whitespace, comment, ';' or end of input (line 2, column 1)
"create constraint on (n:`Person`) assert n.`role` is unique"
 ^
```

presumably from the setup statement:

```
Graph Setup:
create constraint on (n:`Person`) assert n.`name` is unique
create constraint on (n:`Person`) assert n.`role` is unique
...
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to create multiple constraints through the webconsole in one go.

In the web console you need to run the create constraints as separate statements.

Through the neo4j-shell you can run the complete 'script'.

Comment: The script would have to have semicolons at the end of each statement.